# Making scoped functions accessible from a main onload function within the <head>

Tags: javascript

An oversimplified sample of my code:

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  main();
  
  function main() {
    if(document.readyState == 'complete') {
      function a() { /*do stuff*/ }
      function b() { /*do stuff*/ }
    } else {
      setTimeout(function() { main(); }, 1000);
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript: main();">
  <div onclick="javascript: a();"></div>
  <div onclick="javascript: b();"></div>
</body>
```

I am wondering if there is a way for onclick events for `a()` and `b()` to be recognised without putting the `<script>` tag at the end of the document. I know I could do that relatively easily by making variables and functions global, but it's hardly good practice. I could probably utilise closures, but my original code has more functions than 2, and it would be quite a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I could do that relatively easily by making variables and functions global, but it's hardly good practice.

If you're going to use `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers, you have to make those functions accessible globally.

Which is one of the many reasons not to use them.

> ...without putting the  tag at the end of the document.

That's an odd requirement, as that's [where the `script` tag should go](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

But you can do it in a couple of ways:

1. Using the `DOMContentLoaded` event, and hooking up your handlers using `addEventListener` within your event handler for it.
2. Using a `setTimeout` loop to wait for the elements to appear (usually this is a backstop for environments that don't have `DOMContentLoaded`, if there are any left).
3. Using event delegation, where you hook the event on `document` or `document.body`, then check whether the event travelled through the elements you're interested by looking at `event.target` and its parent elements (or using the relatively-new `closest` method).

Barring a really good reason for keeping the `script` in `head`, your best bet here is:

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="divA">divA</div>
  <div id="divB">divB</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  main();
  
  function main() {
    document.getElementById("divA").addEventListener("click", function a() {
       console.log("a click");
    });
    document.getElementById("divB").addEventListener("click", function b() {
       console.log("b click");
    });
  }
</script>
</body>
```

...where using `id`s is **just an example**. In practice, you can often identify the relevant elements via a CSS selector you can use with `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`.

---

Side note: You don't use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol on `onxyz`-attribute-style event handlers. (You use it where a URL is expected, such as an `href` or a bookmark.)

Comment: Would you please elaborate on points 2 and 3? It would be nice to see some examples. Thank you. The odd requirement is mine. I am crazy and do not like seeing script tags outside of the head. I find the approach lazy and difficult to manage down the road. If I am creating a simple page for laymen to use, they will not be happy about scrolling all the way down to fix settings either.

Comment: @Pyromonk - All due respect, I strongly suggest reconsidering that viewpoint. It's neither lazy nor hard to manage: Just put them before `</body>` and they're just as easy to find and manage there. You don't have to "scroll all the way down" on any computer with a key combination for "go to end" (which is all of them). :-) Re elaboration: You can't swing a dead cat on the 'net without examples of #3. #2 is surely self-explanatory? `setTimeout(main, 50)` where `main` checks if the document is ready and, if not, does that `setTimeout` again.

Comment: Your example is pretty much what my code is at the moment. From my experience, using the javascript protocol is a good practice, as certain mobile devices fail to interpret it properly otherwise. Sure, it's a crutch, and I might be outdated.

Comment: @Pyromonk - Yes, the example *is* very like your code, intentionally. But the `script` tag is in the right place and `a` and `b` are still not globals. Re `javascript:` - Citation? I flatly guarantee you that there is no mobile browser in use in 2019 (or at any point, frankly) that requires you to have `javascript:` on `onxyz` attribute event handlers. Not even one. You're confusing it with `href`.

Comment: I've dealt with an online browser game ~5 years ago where the ctrl+enter functionality did not work for mobile devices due to lack of the javascript protocol mention, but, once again, things develop much faster these days, and I might simply be stuck in my old boots. Thank you very much for your elaborate response and help.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the script element won't help.

The `a` and `b` functions exist in the scope of the `main` function and are not accessible outside it.

The `onclick` functions depend on `a` and `b` being globals.

Either make them globals or transform the `onclick` attributes into JavaScript `addEventListener` calls (inside the `main` function).

Comment: Yes, I apologise for phrasing it poorly. By moving the tag I implied getting rid of the main function and putting everything into global scope.